# Point storage format: lat/lon or lon/lat?

Tags: gis, postgis, geodjango

First time user of PostGIS here.

I've been inserting my `POINT` fields in the conventional lat/lon order for a while now but it seems like when I explore PostGIS, it launches a map and it appears that the coordinates are read in lon/lat format, meaning everything is off from what I initially thought. I notice this is the case in Django admin as well for PointField.

Does PostGIS enforce a particular order or is the order up to me? Are there any repercussions from storing them as lat/lon, e.g. will distance calculations be off?

Comment: This question is not asking the community to "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource", and should be re-opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostGIS's [`ST_MakePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) expects (x, y) order, which corresponds to (longitude, latitude) order. Storing it in reverse order would simply be incorrect.

There's some good reading here: https://macwright.org/lonlat/

I personally advocate for lon/lat order in general, since that is equivalent to the mathematical x/y convention. But in any case, you must always verify with the software you are using; you don't get to pick.